# Trigger newsletter success subscription message without refresh

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, newsletter

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0

I have two types of Newsletter Subscription. One is the default, wherein after a user subscribes, the page will reload and the message will be displayed at the top. Another one is AJAX in a Modal, wherein after subscribing, the page won't reload but the message will not appear. It does subscribe the user because I can see it on **Newsletter -> Newsletter Subscribers** at the admin panel.

I want it to appear inside the modal without refreshing the page, and it won't appear again at the top like the default ones when a user refreshes the page.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by manually adding the message directly on a hidden `<div>` that gets displayed/showed when the Ajax submit is successful. That `<div>` is just below the `<form>`'s end tag.

This is the code for the message:

```
<div class="form-success" id="successForm">
  <ul class="messages">
    <li class="success-msg">
      <ul>
        <li>Thank you for your subscription.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```